# How can I stop a MySQL query if it takes too long?

Tags: mysql, timeout

Is it possible to timeout a query in MySQL?

That is, if any query exceeds the time I specify, it will be killed by MySQL and it will return an error instead of waiting for eternity.

Comment: To help us answer the question - Are you trying to do this in, or outside, your code?  And if you would like an answer for a specific language, which one?

Comment: I don't know any ANSI SQL for that, but I know how to do it in a few consuming applications -- how are they connecting?  There is the `join-limit` syntax associated per connection and quite a bit you can do in the application.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm stupid, i forgot to specify things. i'm not trying to do this in my code, i wanna know, if it's possible to do this query timeout in mysql self, something like:
query runs for 120 seconds, limit is 120 so mysql will kill this query and return some error or something. i've issue with 3rd party code which is nasty and i don't have permission to edit it. i need to kill that query in mysql, not in code.

Comment: this works: http://serverfault.com/a/402076/280625

Answer (score 10):

There is a nice Perl script on CPAN to do just this:
http://search.cpan.org/~rsoliv/mysql-genocide-0.03/mysql-genocide

One only needs to schedule it to run with the proper parameters. Create a CRONtab file **/etc/cron.d/mysql_query_timeout** to schedule it to run every minute:

`* * * * * root /path/to/mysql-genocide  -t 7200 -s -K`

Where 7200 is the maxiumum allowed execution time in seconds. The -s switch filters out all except SELECT queries. The -K switch instructs the script to kill the matching processes.

The root user should be able to run local mysql tools without authentication otherwise you will need to provide credentials on the command line.

Comment: These days, a more up-to-date/maintained version of that code lives at https://github.com/dailymotion/mysql-genocide

Answer (score 9):

I just set up the following bash script as a cron job to accomplish this with MySQL 5.0 (kills any query that has been executing for more than 30 seconds).  Sharing it here in case it proves useful to anyone (apologies if my bash scripting style is inefficient or atrocious, it is not my primary development language):

```
#!/bin/bash
linecount=0
processes=$(echo "show processlist" | mysql -uroot -ppassword)
oldIfs=$IFS
IFS='
'
echo "Checking for slow MySQL queries..."
for line in $processes
do
    if [ "$linecount" -gt 0 ]
        then
            pid=$(echo "$line" | cut -f1)
            length=$(echo "$line" | cut -f6)
            query=$(echo "$line" | cut -f8)
            #Id User    Host    db  Command Time    State   Info
            if [ "$length" -gt 30 ]
                then
                    #echo "$pid = $length"
                    echo "WARNING:  Killing query with pid=$pid with total execution time of $length seconds! (query=$query)"
                    killoutput=$(echo "kill query $pid" | mysql -uroot -ppassword)
                    echo "Result of killing $pid:  $killoutput"
            fi
    fi
    linecount=`expr $linecount + 1`
done
IFS=$oldIfs
```

Answer (score 9):

I thought it has been around a little longer, but according to [this](http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/),

> MySQL 5.7.4 introduces the ability to set server side execution time limits, specified in milliseconds, for top level read-only SELECT statements.

```
SELECT 
MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = 1000 --in milliseconds
* 
FROM table;
```

Note that this only works for read-only SELECT statements.

Comment: NB:  Renamed to MAX_EXECUTION_TIME in v 5.7.8

Answer (score 8):

Starting with MySQL 5.1 you can create a stored procedure to query the information_schmea.PROCESSLIST table for all queries that match your criteria for "long running" then iterate over a cursor to kill them.  Then setup that procedure to execute on a recurring basis in the event scheduler.

See: http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=106

Comment: Can something similar be setup for mysql 5.0 or is it 5.1 specific?

Comment: dead link. archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20080323063602/http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=106

Answer (score 7):

The MySQL forum has some threads about this.

[This post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,28504,72056#msg-72056) details how to set up timeouts on the server using innodb_lock_wait_timeout.

[Here's a way to do it programmatically](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,28504,137927#msg-137927), assuming you're using JDBC.

Answer (score 5):

I think this old question needs an updated answer.

You can set a `GLOBAL` timeout for all your read-only `SELECT` queries like this:

`SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=1000;`

The time specified is in milliseconds.

If you want the timeout only for a specific query, you can set it inline like this:

`SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ my_column FROM my_table WHERE ...`

MySQL returns an error instead of waiting for eternity.

Note that this method only works for read-only `SELECT`s. If a `SELECT` statement is determined not to be read-only, then any timer set for it is cancelled and the following NOTE message is reported to the user:

`Note 1908 Select is not a read only statement, disabling timer`

For statements with subqueries, it limits the top `SELECT` only. It does not apply to `SELECT` statements within stored programs. Using the `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` hint in `SELECT` statements within a stored program will be ignored.

Comment: This is the one working in MySql 5.7.21 running on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the egrep above would find "2000".
Why not try just selecting the id as well, and avoiding all of that posh shell stuff:

```
mysql -e 'select id from information_schema.processlist where info is not null and time > 30;'
```

Answer (score 3):

Since MySQL 5.7.8 there is [max_execution_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time) option that defines the execution timeout for SELECT statements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my script :

```
mysql -e 'show processlist\G' |\
egrep -b5 'Time: [6-9]{3,10}' |\
grep 'Id:' |\
cut -d':' -f2 |\
grep -v '155' |\ ## Binary Log PID
sed 's/^ //' |\
while read id
do
    mysql -e "kill $id;"
done
```