# mysql auto kill query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible mysql to auto kill queries which took more than let`s say 20 seconds ?

Comment: You mean abort a running query? Something like `Ctrl c`? Or do you mean programming auto abort after 20 sec?

Comment: that's dangerous if the query took more than 20 seconds is a write operation, which might lead to table corruption

Comment: @ajreal: If this is the case, MySQL should fix this bug. A table should never ever get corrupted when you cancel the query. A dbms should be reliable, that's why you use a dbms in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup MySQL query timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137084/setup-mysql-query-timeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for maatkit utility called mk-kill that will kill queries that match certain criteria.

Comment: do we need to install anything for it ???? or we can simply execute the command , cuz for me it says , mk-kill command not found

Comment: The tool is now known as `pt-kill`, from Percona. You will need to install it. See http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write a program which does it. Your program would use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to discover the currently running queries and how long they've been running, then issue a `KILL` query to terminate one.

Answer (score 1):

Install the RubyGem `mysql_manager` (`sudo gem install mysql_manager`) and then add a command like this to your crontab:

```
mysql-manager --kill --kill:user api --kill:max-query-time 30 --log:level DEBUG
```

For more options, run `mysql-manager --help`.

You might need to specify an alternative `--db:dsn`, `--db:username`, or `--db:password`.

Read more about it here: https://github.com/osterman/mysql_manager