# mysql query timeout kill (pt-kill)

Tags: mysql

I have an expensive reporting query that can take 1-20+ seconds to run. (Depending on how much data it has)

Is there a way to kill a mysql process/query from running after a certain amount of time?

I see this:

[mysql auto kill query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955775/mysql-auto-kill-query)

Is this the best route? I have also read that I should try to improve my queries. I will look into this too, but I am just asking for suggestions on the best route.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup MySQL query timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137084/setup-mysql-query-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
show processlist;
```

then find the query that you want to kill then run

```
kill "1";
```

1 is the id of the query you want to kill you have to choose it according to the list

Comment: I understand how to kill queries, I just want to have an automated process that kills queries that are running long to free up memory.

Comment: look here then http://serverfault.com/questions/401828/how-to-automatically-kill-slow-mysql-queries-after-n-seconds