# How to close mysql connection automatically after specified time in python?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I want to close MySQL database connection after 50 sec automatically if queries are taking more than 50 sec? Is there any option in python while making connection or any other solution to do that ?

Comment: This may give some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137084/setup-mysql-query-timeout

Comment: @PaulF , thanks for the answer . is there any solution in python for this ?

Comment: Not sure about Python - I was looking at doing similar in C# & using a separate thread or timer.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference site for python database connection](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html)

Look **Connection** in this site they might explained about **timeout** for **query**, you can pass an **integer** which is in **seconds**

Comment: this is not working for mysql and it is showing invalid variable